# Haskell: Slow infinite list for Verlet Integration

Tags: performance, haskell, verlet-integration

I am using Haskell to make a Verlet integrator to model gravity. The integrator uses the first two positions of the object as seeds and generates the rest after this.

I thought a nice way of making this in Haskell would be to use an infinite list. However, when implemented I find that it runs very slowly for large times (Haskell 1700 time steps: 12 seconds, Python 1700 time steps: < 1 second)

Here is the relevant code for a 1d integrator that has similar performance:

```
verletStep dt acc xn xn1 = 2*xn1 - xn + (acc xn1)*dt*dt

verlet dt acc x0 x1 = x0 : x1 : next (verlet dt acc x0 x1)
  where
    next (xn : xs@(xn1:_)) = (verletStep dt acc xn xn1) : next xs
```

I also tried using `zipWith` to generate the infinite list but it has similar performance.

Why does this take so long? The garbage collection itself is around 5 seconds. Is there a nice way to make this run faster?

Comment: try to write it tail-recursive

Comment: @viorior That won't help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definition...

```
verlet dt acc x0 x1 = x0 : x1 : next (verlet dt acc x0 x1)
  where
    next (xn : xs@(xn1:_)) = (verletStep dt acc xn xn1) : next xs
```

... leads to  `verlet dt acc x0 x1` being calculated many times unnecessarily, thus building a lot of unneeded lists. That can be seen by working out a time step by hand:

```
verlet dt acc x0 x1
x0 : x1 : next (verlet dt acc x0 x1)
x0 : x1 : next (x0 : x1 : next (verlet dt acc x0 x1))
x0 : x1 : (verletStep dt acc x0 x1) : next (x1 : next (verlet dt acc x0 x1))
```

The solution is to eliminate the unnecessary list-building:

```
verlet dt acc x0 x1 = x0 : x1 : x2 : drop 2 (verlet dt acc x1 x2)
  where
     x2 = verletStep dt acc x0 x1
```

`drop 2` removes the first two elements of a list (in this case, `x1` and `x2`, which we have already prepended). `verlet` is called recursively with the second position, `x1`, and the newly calculated third one, `x2`. (Compare with the original definition, in which `verlet` is called recursively with the same arguments. That should raise suspicion.)